# Angular ngRoute resolve with promises

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am building an angular application and try to load my data upfront using resolve of the ngRoute module.

When I navigate to a certain view, I add several promises to the resolve object.  I then need to take these in as properties in my controller.

I was wondering if there is not a cleaner method to achieve this.  Can I call a function from the resolve which fills up my data-object (simple angular service containing only data) and then inject only this object as a parameter into my controller?

I would like to only inject my contactData into my controller and have this filled up with the 3 properties:

```
resolve: {
            routeData: [
                'contactData', 'contactService', function (contactData, contactService) {
                    return contactService.loadContacts('auto_failed').then(function (response) {
                        contactData.contacts = response.items;
                    });
                }
            ],
            contactData: [
                'contactData', function (contactData) {
                    contactData.mode = 'auto_failed';
                    return contactData;
                }
            ],
            conflictTypes: [
                'contactData', 'contactService', function (contactData, contactService) {
                    return contactService.loadConflictTypes().then(function (response) {
                        contactData.conflictTypes = response.items;
                    });
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: not sure about you question "Can I call a function from the resolve which fills up my data-object (simple angular service containing only data) and then inject only this object as a parameter into my controller?"

Comment: from the documentation of ngRoute i get ' An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.'.  What i did is create data-object that contains all required data.  In my resolve I would like to simly fill this object and then pass in only one dependency in my controller instead several different object.

Suppose I want to load 3 arrays before i enter my controller: 'persons', 'companies' and 'job titles'.  I could then write a resolve with 3 promises returning these 3 arrays.  Or what i would like is to have one object injected 'controllerData' containing the arrays.